# how do I add a sound to a tabBadge unread message count when it updates in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a tabBadge that counts new unread messages.

tabs.html

```
<ion-tab [root]="messages" tabTitle="Messages" tabIcon="chatboxes" tabBadgeStyle="danger" tabBadge="{{getUnreadMessagesCount()}}"></ion-tab>
```

tabs.ts

```
computeUnreadMessagesCount() {
  this.unreadMessagesCount = 0;
  if (this.conversationList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.conversationList.length; i++) {
      this.unreadMessagesCount += this.conversationList[i].messages.length - this.conversationsInfo[i].messagesRead;
      if (this.unreadMessagesCount == 0) {
        this.unreadMessagesCount = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

getUnreadMessagesCount() {
  if (this.unreadMessagesCount) {
    if (this.unreadMessagesCount > 0) {
      return this.unreadMessagesCount;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

What I would like to do is insert a short sound or beep whenever the unread message count is increased.  I would prefer not to use cordova-plugin-nativeaudio as this has not been updated in 2 years. Is there a simple solution to a sound without a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was editing to following code to include this.insertSound(); into the this.unreadMessagesCount (line 5).  Inserting it as said in the previous answer makes the method insertSound() run in a loop which freezes the App.

```
computeUnreadMessagesCount() {
  this.unreadMessagesCount = 0;
  if (this.conversationList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.conversationList.length; i++) {
      this.unreadMessagesCount += this.conversationList[i].messages.length - this.conversationsInfo[i].messagesRead, this.insertSound();
      if (this.unreadMessagesCount == 0) {
        this.unreadMessagesCount = null;
      }
    }
  }
}



insertSound() {
  console.log('sound inserted');
  // some sound method here
}
```

Comment: How can you hear sound using `insertSound()` function. It is just printing a text to the console. This is not the answer what you ask in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not prefer to use `cordova-plugin-nativeaudio` plugin you do it using [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). To use [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), You do not need any plugins or additional node modules. But you need to add [audiocontext-polyfill.js](https://github.com/shinnn/AudioContext-Polyfill/blob/master/audiocontext-polyfill.js) JavaScript file to ensure that deprecated API methods and vendor prefixing will not be an issue when using the Web Audio API inside a modern browser.

- Download the above mentioned JavaScript file.
- Create a **js** directory inside the **src/assets/** directory.
- Place the downloaded file into the **src/assets/js/** directory.
- Create a **sounds** directory inside the **src/assets/** directory and add your own MP3 tracks(In my case it is beep.mp3) into there.

**`Import` audiocontext-polyfill.js file inside the src/index.html file as below.**

```
<body>
  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <script src="assets/js/audiocontext-polyfill.js"></script>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Create a service which manages the API functionality for the audio.**

```
ionic generate provider audio
```

**Add `AudioProvider` to providers array in `app.module.ts` file.**

```
import { AudioProvider } from '../providers/audio/audio';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    AudioProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Do not forget to `import` `HttpClientModule` to `app.module.ts` file.**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Change your `AudioProvider` as below.**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare const AudioContext;
declare const webkitAudioContext;

@Injectable()
export class AudioProvider {

  private TRACK: any = null;
  private AUDIO: any;
  private SOURCE: any;
  private CONTEXT: any = new (AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)();
  private GAIN: any = null;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  loadSound(track: string): void {

    this.http.get(track, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
      .subscribe((arrayBufferContent: any) => {
        this.setUpAudio(arrayBufferContent);
      });
  }

  setUpAudio(bufferedContent: any): void {
    this.CONTEXT.decodeAudioData(bufferedContent, (buffer: any) => {
      this.AUDIO = buffer;
      this.TRACK = this.AUDIO;
      this.playSound(this.TRACK);
    });
  }

  playSound(track: any): void {
    if (!this.CONTEXT.createGain) {
      this.CONTEXT.createGain = this.CONTEXT.createGainNode;
    }
    this.GAIN = this.CONTEXT.createGain();
    this.SOURCE = this.CONTEXT.createBufferSource();
    this.SOURCE.buffer = track;
    this.SOURCE.connect(this.GAIN);
    this.GAIN.connect(this.CONTEXT.destination);

    this.SOURCE.start(0);
  }

  stopSound(): void {
    if (!this.SOURCE.stop) {
      this.SOURCE.stop = this.SOURCE.noteOff;
    }
    this.SOURCE.stop(0);
  }
}
```

**Now you can use `AudioProvider` to play audio from any of your components as below.**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  track: string = 'assets/sounds/beep.mp3';

  constructor(private audio: AudioProvider) {}

  getUnreadMessagesCount() {
  if (this.unreadMessagesCount) {
    if (this.unreadMessagesCount > 0) {
      this.playSound();
      return this.unreadMessagesCount;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

  playSound() {
    this.audio.loadSound(this.track)
  }
}
```

**Hope this will help you to do what you need. I have created sample project related to this answer. You can find it at [this github repo](https://github.com/sudarshanadayananda/Ionic3-Web-Audio-API). Any queries will be accepted.**

Comment: Tried using this as written.  The beep plays continuously and crashes the app.

Comment: Did you try my git hub project?

Comment: I test my sample app which is in git hub only in browser. now i tested in device. it is working devices as well. clone project from git hub and try running it and change it according to your requirement. let me know if there is any issue